# Dropdown selected duplicated IPhone 5+

Tags: jquery, html, iphone, drop-down-menu

I have to display a dropdown using optgroup as follow:

HTML:

```
<select id="Cities" name="Cities">
   <optgroup label="Group1">
        <option value="City1">City1</option>
        <option value="City2">City2</option>
        <option value="City3">City3</option>
        <option value="City4">City4</option>
        <option value="City5">City5</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group2">
        <option value="City6">City6</option>
        <option value="City7">City7</option>
        <option value="City8">City8</option>
        <option value="City9">City9</option>
        <option value="City10">City10</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#Cities').val('City1');
```

I need to set **one** selected value but it always set **two** values as selected when I browse with safari IPhone5+.

[image]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovb6gvuf/)

Comment: I found out that this bug was reported and apperently never fixed: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6569965

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented in the question, this is a [bug](http://discussions.apple.com/thread/6569965) on safari for iphone, and there's nothing to do but **not** setting a `selected` attribute, or not using `optgroups`.